# .htpasswd path in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp, .htpasswd

My .htpasswd file is in 'www' folder in wamp. My .htaccess file is also in same 'www' folder.I want to set path for .htpasswd in .htaccess file.  How to set path in AuthUserFile

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile www/.htpasswd    **path incorrect
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use the full path to your .htpasswd file.

Create a .php file in the same folder, containing the following code :

```
<?php
echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/.htpasswd';
?>
```

Then access it via your browser and it should display the full path you'll need to put in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody got an 500 error using the path from `dirname(__FILE__)`, try to use the server path in your htaccess. You can find out what your path is with

```php
<php 
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

For example:
`home/www/xyz/path/to/htpasswd/.htpasswd`